# Adding push notifications to android all for weather

Tags: android

I am building an app for a friend's website, part of the app is we want to add notifications for weather during the winter, we are looking at using an XML rss feed from environment Canada and I'm working on how to have that information pop up as a notification... Similar to google news weather info that just shows up in the notification bar.

Would I have to set it up on his website server for me to pull the info from or can I do it all in the app.

Update: just to add some info, I dont want any page or section for weather, I just want a service running in the background to have notifications pop up to warn users when there's bad weather.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying so far?

Comment: I'm trying to use xmlpullparser but I'm not sure reading about google cloud messaging if that would be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Having a service in your device pulling a rss does not seem to be a good option. It will consume a lot of battery and resources (like network data) for high query frequencies, and it's almost useless for low frequency values.

You need a server for making push notifications (as you said, through Google GCM) to your registered devices when this service detects the bad weather or whatever you want to notify.

If you only want to check the weather you can make requests everytime the user opens the app but I think that's not what you are looking for.